# Time to verify a signature on a long message

Tags: rsa, digital-signature, dsa

I'm studying the speed (time to verify) a signed message with RSA or DSA over different processors

In this link, there are benchmarks for **the time to verify a signature on a short message (59 bytes)** 
http://bench.cr.yp.to/results-sign.html

But **I need the times to verify a signature on a long message (1500) byte** , Is there a relation between the time to verify a signature on a message and the message length ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to verification:

1. Hashing the message, and then
2. performing a public key operation and comparison on the supplied signature and the hash

1) takes longer for longer messages, whereas 2) will only depend on the size of the public key. Also, 2) will dominate 1) except for very long messages.

When benchmarking verification times you are probably only interested in #2, so you might as well use a short message as the benchmark you cited does. You can benchmark hashing times separately if you're interested in that.

Comment: In another way, haw many clock cycles does RSA with exponent of 65537 need to verify ?

Sure Times will be different according to processor, that's why I asked for number of clock cycles